# How to calculate impulse required to move an object vertically upward by given distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, work

Suppose I have a stationary object of mass $m$ and I want to apply a momentary force in the vertical direction so that it just reaches the height $h$.

So how do I calculate the impulse required in this case?

Also how do I exactly define the $\delta t$ for the momentary force? Shall I just take 1 second?

Edit 1: Suppose I take $\delta t$ = 0.1 sec, is there anyway I can calculate the impulse now?

Edit 2: This edit is in response to the "on hold" tag. The object is in water which I didn't mention earlier but later in the comments. Thanks to @Floris for taking the time to answer even though I didn't mention this initially.

Comment: Well, what you take as the duration of the momentary force really depends on what kind of force you're thinking about - I'm not sure how we can help here withoutfurther information.

Comment: Well we have $dP = F\delta t$, but it depends on how long you will apply the force for, or what is the strength of your force. If you have a $F = F_0$, then $\delta t = \frac{dP}{F_0}$.

Comment: This is best solved through energy changes and then solved for the average force applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no air friction, you compute the initial velocity needed from conservation of energy:

$$ \frac12 mv^2=mgh $$

The impulse needed is $mv=F\Delta t$. The product of these ($F, \Delta t$) is constant - shorter time implies higher force.

The above assumes the time of impact is short enough not to affect the over all time (otherwise you need to solve the trajectory more carefully)

Note that if drag cannot be ignored (as is probably the case in your problem, as you later specified in the comments that this is "in water"), the treatment is more complex. Assuming that the initial impulse is still very short, we have to now consider two additional non-trivial forces:

1. Buoyancy (which means that the increase in potential energy is smaller than expected)
2. Drag - which we will assume to be quadratic in velocity, and with a constant "shape factor". The latter assumption ($C_D=0.5$ for a sphere) is usually OK in a turbulent regime of Reynolds numbers; a more precise treatment would have to adjust for changing $C_D$ with changing velocity / Reynolds number.

There is another factor that can play a role; when a sphere is accelerated in a liquid, its inertia appears to be increased by an amount equal to half the mass of the displaced fluid. Intuitively this makes sense - when you move an object through a liquid, the liquid also moves, but not as fast as the object. The additional kinetic energy of the liquid has to come from somewhere - this gives rise to an apparently greater inertia of the sphere.

The buoyancy is of course given by $\rho V g$, meaning that the net gain in potential energy is $(m-\rho V) gh$; we can think of this as though the object is moving in a reduced gravity $g' = g\left(1-\frac{\rho V}{m}\right)$.

The equation of motion for a projectile being launched vertically, and subject to both (constant) gravity and (quadratic) drag can be written as

$$m\ddot{y} = -mg +\rho V g - C\ddot{y}$$

Where the constant $C=\frac12\rho A C_D$.

The solution for this is given on [this page of the hyperphysics site](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/quadrag.html). Given a terminal velocity

$$v_t = \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{C_D\rho A}}$$

And characteristic time $\tau$

$$\tau = \frac{v_t}{g}$$

The height reached is

$$y_{peak}=-v_t \tau \log\left[\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{v_0}{v_t}\right)\right]$$

In your case, you know $y_{peak}$ and you would like to find $v_0$, so we need to invert the equation. Thus we get

$$v_0 = v_t \tan\left[\cos^{-1}\left(e^{-\frac{y_{peak}}{v_t\tau}}\right)\right]$$

Finally, we have to substitute $g'$ for $g$ in the expressions for $\tau$ and $v_t$, and you have your answer for the initial velocity.

From which it is a short step to the impulse needed.

Note - if you look at the expression for $v_0$ you can see that as $y_{peak}>v_t\tau$, the velocity required quickly becomes bigger.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, actually the particle is inside water, but if i ignore the water resistance, can i also ignore the buoyancy in the energy conservation equation since the mass is already cancelled out. Maybe while calculating the impulse only, I should take the buoyancy into account, and use volume * (density of particle - density of water) for the mass. Do yo think this will do?

Comment: You cannot ignore drag or buoyancy. You are right that the change in potential energy can effectively account for it by using a "reduced mass" (density adjusted by density of water), but ignoring drag is almost certainly wrong. Check this by computing drag force $F=\frac12\rho v^2 A C_D$  - is it a significant fraction of the force of gravity or not? That is going to depend on your geometry and required accuracy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Taking both buoyancy and drag into account, can i use the following equation then: $m_agh - 0.5m_av^2 = F_Dh$ where $m_a$ = apparent mass taking buoyancy into account. This is when it is still water, correct?

Comment: Drag is a function of velocity...

Comment: The velocity will not be constant - it will change throughout the trajectory. There is a closed form solution for a projectile with quadratic drag - I will look it up and add it to my answer. May take me a little time...

Comment: hi, i tried using the drag as a function of changing velocity. can u please check if this is the correct way: https://imgur.com/tawlHt4

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/quadrag.html for the correct treatment

Comment: Thank u so much, that was really helpful. I used the webpage for the calculations. I guess I need to read more on how those formula are derived. If u can refer something, that had be great. If not, still its ok. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2617526 - I added some more math, but not a complete derivation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your effort. Can you please refer me to the exact derivations. I am not asking you to show it here, but I guess you may already know where I can find the complete derivation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found a few online videos with the derivation, but they seemed to have some suspicious "download this player" type links which triggers my spider sense that there is a Trojan about to be installed - so I would prefer not to give you the link. If I find something (or decide to do the derivation myself) I will update.